# How to properly reverse the Django auth login?

Tags: django, django-urls

Ok, so all I want to do is to redirect the user to the login page based on some logic in my view. I've tried:

```
reverse('django.contrib.auth.views.login')
```

and I've also tried creating a unique entry in my app's urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^login/', login, name='my-login'),
)
```

Then in my view

```
reverse('my-login')
```

but they both give me a NoReverseMatch error.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Complete urlconf? Maybe you inserted this part for the login somehow wrong. Also try `'my_login'` instead of `'my-login'`. Not sure this matters, but I always use underscored names,

Comment: Ok. So yeah, in the end its a string. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's definitely something wrong elsewhere in your urls. I'm able to reverse the auth login url pattern just fine:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
print reverse('django.contrib.auth.views.login')
```

Comment: I'm marking your's as the answer because you reminded me how easy it is to debug this problem. The above still doesn't work but I realized that when I thought I was updating my urls.py the changes where never making it to the server. So adding the named url pattern did work once I was actually using it. I just had to go into the shell and use a few pdb break points to figure that out.

Comment: For this solution to work, you'd need something like this in your urls.py: `url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),` right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. My answer assumes that, based on the code sample supplied by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `admin` URL namespace to get the login URL:

```
>>> from django.urls import reverse
>>> reverse('admin:login')
'/admin/login/'
```

See the relevant section of [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls). URL namespaces have been available since Django 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

for django 3.1:

```
urlpatterns = [
     ....  
     path('login/', admin.site.login),
     ....
]
```